# cakephp - checking if session is set

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm new to cakephp and following this tutorial.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

I have created the blog and the user authentication system. I'm trying to display a link to sign in(if the user isn't signed in) or display a link to sign out (if the user is signed in).

So, essentially I'm checking to see if the session is set. If it is, display a link to log out. If the session isn't set, display a link to sign in.

This is in my file index.ctp located in View/Posts/index.ctp. The file containing the login and logout functions are located in Controller/UsersController.php.

```
<?php 
if($this->Auth->User('id')){ 
    echo $this->Html->link('Log Out', array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'logout'));
}

if(!($this->Auth->User('id'))){ 
    echo $this->Html->link('Log In', array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'login'));
}
?>
```

I'm getting the following error: Fatal error: Call to a member function User() on a non-object. I know this means the object isn't defined, but I'm not sure how to reference it to another controller.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Auth is a [component](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1241/Core-Components) and thus is not available in your view, those are called [helpers.](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1357/Core-Helpers)

To access Session var within a view you would do

```
$this->Session->check('Auth.User');
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's twice you've helped me today. It's frustrating learning this stuff all over again. I finally got comfortable with php, decided to move onto cakephp and now I know nothing all over again!

Comment: glad I helped :), edited my answer with links. Basically in cakephp you have concepts of helpers, which is sort of like libraries to use across views, components to use across controllers and behaviors to use across models. http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1357/Core-Helpers http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1241/Core-Components http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1319/Core-Behaviors